# Determining if Outlook Appointment is opened as Single Occurrence or Series?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm building an Outlook add-in in Visual Studio 2010, using VSTO with VB.net, to sync Outlook Calendar data with an internal, proprietary Calendar.  Our users want to be able to open a recurring appointment in Outlook, send the Appointment details and have the internal calendar update with the recurring appointment details.

I actually have code in place that works just fine for creating recurring appointments and single appointments.  The problem is that I can see no difference (when viewing the `AppointmentItem` or `RecurrenceItem` members) between a single occurrence of the series being opened, or if the entire series has been opened; all the data is the same, all the functions have the same result.  I can see there's the difference in menu bars, but I don't even see a way to detect that difference.

Has anybody run into this, and if so, how did you work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RecurrenceState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206659%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property of AppointmentItem. 

If appointment is open as single occurence, it is equal to olApptOccurrence.
If it is open as series - RecurrenceState is equal to olApptMaster.